# Can objects be called in the subclass?

Tags: java, arrays, object, methods

First, some background information regarding this program. It is set up to create new bank accounts and hold the information for different objects in an object array. In this particular code segment, I am trying to get input from the user (the bank account number) to be validated through the subclass.

This is my main program, where I am attempting to get the bank number to validated through a method in the subclass.

```
for(int x = 0; x < bankAccountArray.length; x++){
     System.out.print("Enter bank account number: ");
          int bankNumber = number.nextInt();
     checkAcctNum(bankNumber, bankAccountArray[x]);
}
```

My subclass works as follows:

```
public int checkAcctNum(int acctNum, SeveralBankAccountsSub object){
    for(int x = 0; x < 10; x++){
        if(acctNum == object.getAcct()) \\runs seperate method within subclass
            return acctNum;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

When I compile, the main program has the following error:

cannot find symbol - method checkAcctNum(int, SeveralBankACcounts Sub)

I have no idea what to do to correct this. I believe it is due to the object array being sent to the subclass, since I am trying to use the information within that array to access all the bank numbers.

Any help would be greatly appreciated - I have been stuck on this for two days now (I am a high school student) and I would be relieved to have this program running correctly.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please share more code. You claim the method should be visible, but there's nothing in pasted code to suggest that. Don't add an answer/comment, just edit the question.

Comment: You don't call objects. You call methods.

Comment: Change `checkAcctNum()` to static method. And call like `SubclassName.checkAcctNum(...)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is what your main class looks like, this is the problem...

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for(int x = 0; x < bankAccountArray.length; x++){
            System.out.print("Enter bank account number: ");
            int bankNumber = number.nextInt();
            checkAcctNum(bankNumber, bankAccountArray[x]);
        }
    }
}
```

`checkAcctNum` doesn't exist on that main class. It exists on your sub class. Therefore you'd have to do something like this:

```
SubClass x = new SubClass()
for(int x = 0; x < bankAccountArray.length; x++){
     System.out.print("Enter bank account number: ");
          int bankNumber = number.nextInt();
     x.checkAcctNum(bankNumber, bankAccountArray[x]);
}
```

Also, if that `for` loop is in your static main method, it can only call a static method on the class that holds your main method.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I didn't want to add the entire program since it would be difficult to find what I was talking about, but what you gave me worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

"Cannot find symbol" means that whatever it's complaining about is not visible from where you're attempting to use it (or it's not defined at all). It's not clear to me where your two methods are, but if they are in two different classes that is probably your problem.